# In PHP, is there a way to loop over just the array keys and not the values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key

For example, currently I am doing this:

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $unused) {
    //use $key here
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to specify the $unused value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach(array_keys($myArray) as $key) {}
```

[API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: +1 however it is more efficient to use regular foreach($myArray as $key => $value) than with array_keys that it is applied to function stack. So unless using it for code readability or later in code you need keys only - dont use array_keys()